# Access LinkLabel through White

Tags: c#, winforms, ui-automation

I have one windows form application. i have created UI Automation script but i am not able to click on LinkLabel on the form. Does anyone know how can we get object of LinkLabel using White UI Library

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my query but using Hyperlink. LinkLabel object can be search using white. It will be considered as Hyperlink.

Thanks
-Amit Gajjar